# Test Nested Tag attribute inside Parent Tag's attribute

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme

I have a tag that is nested inside another tag's attribute.

Exhibit a.

```
<Tag
    input={(
      <NestedTag
        value={this.props.value}
        onChange={this.validate}
      />
    )}
  />
```

What I want to do is check that value inside NestedTag is correct.

In Enzyme, I've got as far as this:

```
expect(
  wrap
    .find(Tag)
    .at(0)
    .prop('input')
).toBe(...tag info goes here);
```

This is as far as I've gotten so far.  I just don't know how to look inside "input" and poke around inside NestedTag.

I know I can use toMatchObject, but I've prefer to check each individual property in isolation.

Comment: What is Tag doing with its input prop?  If it's rendering it as a child somewhere, you should be able to find the element within the component if it's mounted.

Comment: @ChrisB. You were right.  I needed to do a full mount, because I was only using a shallow mount.  If you set that as the answer, I will accept it.  Thanks

Comment: Great! Added as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, if Tag is rendering its `input` prop as a child, you can simply `find` it provided that the component is mounted first.

Cheers!